# Confused in using clearInterval() inside useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function TimeArea() {
  const [theTime, setTheTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleString())

  // Confused here!
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setTheTime(new Date().toLocaleString()), 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return <p>The current time is {theTime}.</p>
}
```

Why would it still output `{theTime}` in the paragraph `<p></p>` when we're just storing `setInterval` inside a variable? and even more so we cleared it before executing the 'interval' variable? How come it would still output time intervals of 1second. Also, I'm confused with the "mount/unmount" terms which is relevant to this problem when I was searching google. I only understand that mount is when the page 'loads' and unmount is when 'closing' or 'switching' to a different page. Forgive me everyone, I really tried searching it on youtube and google as well as the all knowing chatgpt, but I am still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval is cleared only when react removes the **component** from the page (unmount). Mount/unmount in react refer to the individual component, not the entire page.

> Why would it still output {theTime} in the paragraph `<p></p>` when we're just storing setInterval inside a variable?

The `interval` constant doesn't hold the value. It stores the id of the interval, that allows you to clear the interval. Add `console.log(interval)` to the `useEffect` block, and you'll see that it's not time value, and it doesn't update all the time.

Every 1000ms (the interval) the function `setTheTime(new Date().toLocaleString())` is called, and updates `theTime` (sets the state). Setting the state also causes a re-render, and the paragraphs is re-rendered with the new value.

If you only want the date to update on load, use a reference instead:

```js
const { useRef } = React

function TimeArea() {
  const theTime = useRef(new Date().toLocaleString())

  return <p>The current time is {theTime.current}.</p>
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<TimeArea />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner with react (forgive me), I'm just going through with a react tutorial and don't really know any better for now. But I really appreciate your answer, however I'm still confused why the 'setInterval' would output when we're just storing it as a variable.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understood it better now due to your explanation. I really appreciate it so much :) wish I could at least upvote you, but this is a new account and therefore limited. I wish you the best of luck :D